# How to CSS styling with react-dates?

Tags: reactjs, react-dates

I'm using a react-dates package of Airbnb, but I can't styling CSS for it. So, if you used it, please help me.
How to styling CSS for react-dates?

[image] "actual"

I expect the date picker will be

[image]

Comment: try looking at https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates#overriding-styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-dates relies on moment to format date. If what you need is just show a complete date, you need to format your date using the displayFormat prop, like this example:

```
 static defaultProps = {
    Wrapper: styles.Wrapper,
    displayFormat: 'MMM DD YYYY',
    invalid: false,
    disabled: false,
  };
```